# Насчет скорости обработки генераторов списка в Python

Tags: python, list, производительность

Столкнулся с огромной разницей в производительности в зависимости от того, как передается генератор списке. Пытаюсь разобраться в причине.

```
import timeit
print('sum([ ]) - ', timeit.timeit('sum([x*2 for x in range(1000)])', number=1000))
print('sum(( )) - ', timeit.timeit('sum((x*2 for x in range(1000)))', number=1000))
print('sum( ) - ', timeit.timeit('sum(x*2 for x in range(1000))', number=1000))
print('sum(list( )) - ', timeit.timeit('sum(list(x*2 for x in range(1000)))', number=1000))
```

Выдает:

```
sum([ ]) -  0.1341158
sum(( )) -  1.3132869999999999
sum( ) -  1.3040761
sum(list( )) -  1.3090227000000003
```

Почему вариант с [] настолько быстрее работает? Разве он не должен давать примерно ту же производительность, что и list()? Генератор в скобках и без скобок - понятно что одинаково считаются, но почему list() дает ту же скорость и откуда все-таки такая разница с []

*Другой пример*

```
print('any([ ]) - ', timeit.timeit('any([x*2 for x in range(1000)])', number=1000))
print('any(( )) - ', timeit.timeit('any((x*2 for x in range(1000)))', number=1000))
print('any( ) - ', timeit.timeit('any(x*2 for x in range(1000))', number=1000))
print('any(list( )) - ', timeit.timeit('any(list(x*2 for x in range(1000)))', number=1000))
```

Тут ситуация обратная:

```
any([ ]) -  0.11409800000000025
any(( )) -  0.005497499999999711
any( ) -  0.005274499999999627
any(list( )) -  1.3024014
```

Разница частично проистекает из "ленивости" функции any и в случае с чистым генератором (№2 и №3) она возвращает True на первом же числе. Но почему [] и list() имеют такую большую разницу друг с другом? Разве список в этих случаях создается по-разному?

Возможно и упускаю что-то простое, в Питон перешёл недавно. И если кому попадались толковые статьи на эту тему, то прошу поделиться.

[ДОБАВЛЕНО ПОЗЖЕ]

Как оказалось на других платформах результаты могут быть совсем иными. Например прогнал скрипт на Гугл Колабе и получил вот такое (кол-во повторов взял побольше для наглядности):

```
sum([ ]) -  1.04
sum(( )) -  0.78
sum( ) -  0.79
sum(list( )) -  1.27

any([ ]) -  9.84
any(( )) -  0.000072
any( ) -  0.000070
any(list( )) -  12.08
```

То есть на колабе получается более прогнозируемый результат. Собственно я примерно его ожидал получить когда всё это тестирование только затевал, потому и был так удивлён что не сошлось.

Главный вопрос - почему у меня на локале (Python 3.8.1 под Windows 10) возникает разница на порядок между any([ ]) и any(list( )) и между sum([ ]) и остальными вариантами.

Comment: У меня на Python 3.6 так не получается: sum([ ]) -  0.21148989500034077
sum(( )) -  0.15104303000043728
sum( ) -  0.1442236769998999
sum(list( )) -  0.12804498299919942

Comment: Толковое замечание. Прогнал скрипт на гугл колабе и на удивление получил довольно ровные результаты. Похоже что дело в какой-то особенности реализации. Понятнее правда не стало.
Дополнил в текст результы с колаба.

Comment: Я попробовал в колабе 100 прогонов на миллионом range, получил более логичный результат: sum([ ]) -  10.767052626999998
sum(( )) -  7.907912425000006
sum( ) -  7.9287874380000005
sum(list( )) -  12.83785970300002
any([ ]) -  10.155985514999998
any(( )) -  0.00011865199996918818
any( ) -  6.859200004782906e-05
any(list( )) -  12.314442535000012

Comment: То есть списки реально медленнее, чем генераторы, потому что их физически нужно создавать в памяти. Просто на маленьком числе элементов это не так заметно. И ещё я подозреваю, что list comprehension всё же каким-то образом оптимизирован в плане создания списка и поэтому работает несколько быстрее, чем list от generator comprehension.

Comment: Согласен, на колабе получается прогнозируемый результат. Собственно я примерно его ожидал получить когда всё это тестирование только затевал, потому и был так удивлён что не сошлось. Главный вопрос - почему у меня на локале возникает разница на порядок между any([ ]) и any(list( )) и почему sum([ ]) отрабатывает на порядок быстрее других вариантов.  Запускал на Python 3.8.1 под Windows 10.

Comment: В первом варианте списковое включение сразу генерирует список. В последнем, генераторное выражение создаёт генератор, который полностью вычисляется, а потом его результат преобразовывается в список. Как минимум вызовов больше будет.